# Visual Studio 2015 Git "See the Output window for details" but no details there

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing a test to try to pull changes from GitHub to my local Git repo using Visual Studio Team Explorer and getting the "Cannot pull because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before pulling again. See the Output window for details." message.

For others who have received this message, are you seeing any details in the Output window?

I have my Output window set to show output from Source Control - Git, but the last message I see there is from when it opened my repository.  I'm not seeing any errors or detailed messages from the failed pull.  I know I can use other methods to find out the details, like attempt to run the git pull in a git bash shell.  But I wonder if they're supposed to appear in Visual Studio.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue in VS 2019. and I found that you need to change in the output tab the "Show output from" dropdown to "Source control Git" to be able to see the details you are looking for.

See image here for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> I wonder if they're supposed to appear in Visual Studio.

- Supposed? Yes.
- Will they? Well, you see it yourself, they won't.
- Why? Because VS has still very poor git integration. Things like that will happen, brace yourself. The situation improves with every release, so maybe VS15 will be better.